# rsync filter based on an intermediate directory name

Tags: rsync

I want to copy files `/SRC/**/OK/**/*OK*` to  `/DEST/**/OK/**/*OK*` using rsync.

For all the files to copy, there must be a folder named `OK` in the full path and a `OK` in the filename.

I tried

```
rsync -avP --include='**/OK/**/*OK*' --include='*/' --exclude='*' --inplace SRC DEST
```

It doesn't work.

```
rsync -avP --include='*OK*' --include='*/' --exclude='*' --inplace SRC DEST
```

works but it creates all the folders, no matter whether they contain `OK` in the full path or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rsync -am --include='**/OK/**/*OK*' --include='*/' --exclude='*' --delete-excluded SRS DEST
```

Try this one. -m deletes "empty" directories that were created while traversing SRS sub directories, and --delete-excluded to make **rsync** not look like **cp**.